# Question about changing the style of the label when the checkbox is pressed

Tags: html, css

```
<label> 
 <input type="checkbox"> todo
</label>
```

[image]

'display:none;' property is given to the input, and the label is styled to look like a picture.

What if I want to change the background color of the label when the checkbox is pressed?
advice please

Comment: Change the code so that the `label` and the checkbox are siblings and the `label` has a `for` attribute whose value is the `id` of the checkbox (e.g., `<input type="checkbox" id="chk"><label for="chk">todo</label>`) Then you can use the sibling combinator `input:checked + label { background: red }`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey
Thanks to you, I confirmed that the background changes! But what if i have multiple inputs and only want to change the style of the label for what is pressed?

Comment: Try adding more inputs and labels. As long as the IDs (and the corresponding `for` attributes) are unique (and they must be to be valid HTML), that will work fine. If you want different colors for different inputs, either add the id to the selector (e.g., `input#chk:checked + label { background: green; }`) or add a class to those inputs that share a common background (e.g., `input.blue:checked + label { background: blue; }`)

Answer (score 0):

I think this example do the thing.

```css
.checkbox {
    position: realtive;
}

.checkbox input {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox-condition {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background .4s;
}

.checkbox-condition:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}

.checkbox input:checked + .checkbox-condition {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox"> 
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span class="checkbox-condition">TODO</span>
</label>
```